# GridView onClickListener not working

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a gridview inside navigation drawer. The gridview is showing perfectly; even when I touch on a gridview item it's showing focus. But click is not being detected. Please help…
Is it a problem with navigation drawer???
I mean grid view not working in navigation?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/drop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_drawer" >
</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#373737"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#666"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    android:paddingRight="1dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/box1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pref"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/pref" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/temp_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/temp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/sep1"
            android:layout_width="4px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/temp_icon"
            android:background="#3bb9ff" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/sep2"
            android:layout_width="4px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pref" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temp_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sep2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sep1"
            android:text="100 C"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/extra_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/temp_txt"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/temp_txt"
            android:layout_below="@+id/temp_txt"
            android:text="This is extra info panel make some usefull and put here"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/sep4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/box1"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="#222222" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/box2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/box1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" >
    </ScrollView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/sep5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/box2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#222222" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/box3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sep5" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/sep6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/box3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:background="#222222" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/box3333"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sep6"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/box3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_btn_play" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:src="@drawable/img_btn_previous" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:src="@drawable/img_btn_previous" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/sep9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/box3333"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="#222222" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sep9"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:columnWidth="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my code

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) contentView
            .findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    Bitmap[] ic = JsonLibrary.saved_ps_bitmap(getApplicationContext());
    gridView.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ic));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding is as a listener to the class. Let me know if that does anything for you.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a misunderstand between the listeners. In your xml, you have `android:clickable="true"` which refers to `onClick` listener and you declare two `onItemClick` listeners on the `GridView` at runtime.

You should remove this attribute:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Also remove this line:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

This last is not needed because you declare the right one just after it. Then, the dup is not necessary.

To understand, when you use `this` as parameter, you call the implementation of the Activity which needs to be:

```
public class A extends Activity implement OnItemClickListener { }
```

But if you declare this click listener directly on the GridView and not inside the Activity, this is useless.